# Get object as output instead of List in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to get output result as an object but i'm getting result as a list.

My view:

```
def Expense_with_id(request, id):
    details = ExSerializer(Cat.objects.filter(id=id).all(), many=True).data
    return JsonResponse(details, safe=False)

Output:
    [{
      "id": 1,
      "category": 1,
       ...... 

     }]
```

I want my output to be :

```
Expected Output:

    {
      "id": 1,
      "category": 1,
       ...... 

    }
```

How can I achieve this with the current query.

Comment: remove `many=True`

Comment: I tried but it did not work @ruddra

Comment: Try using `get`  instead of `filter` then remove `many=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExSerializer(Cat.objects.get(id=id))`

You are doing `filter()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: I am getting an error ->` object is not iterable` if I remove all and

Answer (score 0):

use get() when you want to get a single unique object, and filter() when you want to get all objects that match your lookup parameters.